# How to sync time on Windows 2008 R2 during startup?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, time-synchronization

I've got a remote Windows 2008 R2 Server which I'd like to sync up time during startup against a list of 5 NTP servers. How could this be accomplished?

EDIT:
Found the solution - I've use Windows Task Scheduler to run "w32tm /resync" on startup when there is network connection, with 30 sec delay.

Should solve the problem.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you find a solution on your own, post it as a separate 'answer' below and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Install ntpd. The builtin time synchronization in windows is far to imprecise to be useful. I use this implementation on my windows machine, pretty easy to setup, you edit a text-file and add your servers.

http://www.meinberg.de/english/sw/time-server-monitor.htm

Be sure to disable W32Time in your services to prevent it from synchronizing time with other services.

Comment: Thanks. I Use Windows Time Agent which does the same - but neither can make it sync on startup.

Comment: Just FYI, you can configure `w32time` service to use NTP without installing anything additional.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but my experience is that W32Time easily accept several seconds of skew which in many cases isn't acceptable. If you still want to use W32Time, you can adjust the frequency it will try to synchronize in the registry.